# Use an Access Database over FTP

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, ftp

I am writing a software and I used MSDN's FTP file download code to download a file from the FTP server. The problem is that the file hence downloaded, is corrupt and when opened with MS Access, asks for a password. To resolve this, I have two options: "Find a way to correctly download the file." **OR** "Directly change the file on the ftp server."

I found the latter to be better and I can't figure a way out. I don't have any bit of code I've tried as I don't have ANY idea.

Any help is appreciated.

Code for FTp

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://admin:123456@192.168.14.155/database.accdb"), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

    'request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "123456")

    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

    Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)

    Using writer As New StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "/database.accdb")
        writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd)
    End Using

    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
```

Comment: Why do you say it is corrupt when it asks for a password?

Comment: I don't enter a password, just hit enter. Also I have noted that the file size (after the transfer) changes by almost 10kbs

Comment: And what happens when you choose compact & repair?

Comment: Hmm... Where is that option ? (MS Access 2013)

Comment: File -->Compact & Repair

Comment: What mode do you use for ftp downloading BINARY or ASCII ?

Comment: All I see is: http://labsvisual.webs.com/Capture.PNG

Comment: @4dmonster take a look at my edit. That's my code.

Comment: try to set UseBinary to True

Comment: isn't working. Still the same error